# Laravel 5.8 syncing / attaching / detaching events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

**Laravel 5.8** is supposed to dispatch the syncing, attaching and detaching events (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases search for *Intermediate Table / Pivot Model Events* section).

**UPDATE**: the release notes have been update after posting this question (more info: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28050 - https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5096).

I tried it out but the following code throws the exception:

**Call to undefined method App\ProjectUser::syncing()**

NOTE: since Laravel 5.8 is supposed to dispatch the syncing event I don't want to use an external package.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Project::class)->using(\App\ProjectUser::class);
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class)->using(\App\ProjectUser::class);
    }
}

class ProjectUser extends Pivot
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::syncing(function ($item) {
            dd('syncing event has been fired!');
        });
    }
}

// web.php
$project = \App\Project::first();
$project->users()->sync([1,2]);
```

I tried to move the boot method from `ProjectUser` to `User` and `Project` but I get the same exception.

Comment: You only have `boot()` method there.

Comment: @Tpojka can you be more specific, please? That is a common way to tell laravel to listen to an event (another way is to create an observer).

Comment: Sorry, didn't use it that way. I fairly use observers but didn't use through boot method. I just searched docs and there is no syncing method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Laravel 5.8, when you are using the methods `sync`, `attach` or `detach` is going to be fired the appropriate model events (creating, updating, saving, ...) for the called action. Note that using `sync`, `attach` or `detach` is not going to fire any event like *syncing*, *attaching* or *detaching*.

More specifically, the sequence of events fired for each element passed to the `sync` method are:

- saving
- creating
- created
- saved

The sequence of events fired for each element passed to the `attach` method are:

- saving
- creating
- created
- saved

The sequence of events fired for each element passed to the `detach` method are:

- deleting
- deleted

So if you want to observe the syncing operation you actually have to observe the saving (or saved) event **from the pivot model** (in this case `ProjectUser`):

```
class ProjectUser extends Pivot
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($item)  {
            // this will die and dump on the first element passed to ->sync()
            dd($item);
        });
    }
}
```

A working example https://github.com/danielefavi/laravel-issue-example

More info on this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28050

The release notes were misleading and they have been changed https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5096.

Answer (score 2):

If  detach method  called without ids (for detach all relations), events are not firing

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27571#issuecomment-493451259

i tried many different way for the solve this need, but it is impossible without use external package or override many method.

I choose [chelout/laravel-relationship-events](https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events) package.

It's look clean and understable. And use with trait.

Comment: Yes you are right, the detach method requires the IDs if you want to fire the events. A solution to detach all elements and have the events as well can be: `$project->users()->detach( User::all()->pluck('id') );`